# Why do reviewers need to be selected again for a revised paper?

Tags: peer-review, journal-workflow

I submitted a paper to a marketing journal and the reviewers recommended a major revision and a minor revision. I had to shorten the text and get professional help for proofreading. I addressed the every single comment of reviewers.

Now, it is in the “Awaiting Reviewers Selection” mode once again. Does anybody explain why the journal editor needs to select new reviewers at this step of review process?

Comment: It seems you've asked some new questions in this post. On this website (actually, this family of websites), it is generally preferred that you put new questions into a new post, since we prefer to have only one question per post. To briefly answer your questions here, if one or more of the previous reviewers requested major revisions, this typically results in the reviewers begin sent your revised manuscript. You can also thoroughly read the answer of Wrzlprmft below, where they have addressed some of your other questions.

Comment: "...he/she will possibly have new suggestions/comments. Isn't that unfair?"  It is not a contest where you try to get something past them.  It is a cooperation to make the paper better.

Comment: Also note that we probably cannot answer your new questions. Both answers provide a selection of possible explanitions but we have no idea what is plausible in your case and thus cannot tell you what is actually happening.

Answer (score 14):

I think that two explanations are possible:

- (At least on of) the reviewers did not agree to review the paper again. This can happen, as a reviewer you are not obligated to review a revision.
- The status on the webpage does not reflect the actual status the paper is in. E.g., the actual status might be 'paper lying on the editor's desk, collecting dust'.

Comment: +1 for the first - there are some journals I review for where you can opt out of this on your first review. And then even if you don't, there's no promise the revision won't come at a really bad time for you.

Comment: Another possibility is their system requires someone to push it through at this point, too, and any "new paper" automatically gets that status.

Answer (score 14):

If you submit a revised paper to a journal, usually a few things happen before it is sent to the reviewers:

- The paper is checked for trivial problems such as broken links or missing figures.
- The editor at least superficially checks whether you addressed the reviewers’ comments appropriately. For example if you did not address a comment the editor considers to be major, the paper may be returned to you immediately without review.
- The editor decides whether all reviewers from the previous round are required to review the manuscript again. For example, if the editor thinks that you addressed all remarks of one reviewer appropriately, sending the manuscript to this reviewer again may be considered a waste of everybody’s time.
- In some situations, the editor may refrain from reüsing a reviewer from the previous round for other reasons, e.g., because this reviewer is known to be unavailable.
- In some situations, the editor may select additional reviewers, e.g., if in light of the first two reviews, the editor wanted a third opinion anyway, but wanted to give you the opportunity to reviese your manuscript before this.

Depending on the editiorial management system, some or all of these points may be comprised in *Awaiting Reviewers Selection.* Or with other words: It may as well mean *Awaiting Editor’s Assessment.*

Another possibility is that the manuscript was already sent to the existing reviewers but one of them declined to review very quickly and now the editor has to select a new reviewer.

Answer (score 4):

The "Awaiting reviewer selection" is likely an automatc status for articles that have been passed to the acting editor (It very much sounds like you are in ScholarOne Manuscripts, S1M). The editor now has to evaluate your revisions and make a decision whether to accept, reject or pass the article on for a second review. The label you see is therefore slightly misleading but means it is back for evaluation in S1M.

Comment: Thank you Peter. I have received a message from the editor stating that my paper was accepted.